# VTK: display subdivided polygon

Tags: vtk

I have created an icosahedron and subdivided it, I am not trying to display it but it seems to be displaying it un-subdivided. Here is my code:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlatonicSolidSource> icosahedron = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlatonicSolidSource>::New();
     icosahedron->SetSolidTypeToIcosahedron();
     icosahedron->Update();

     cout << " Centre is " << icosahedron->GetOutput()->GetCenter()[0] << ", " << icosahedron->GetOutput()->GetCenter()[1] << ", " << icosahedron->GetOutput()->GetCenter()[2] << endl;
     cout << "    There are " << icosahedron->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfPolys() << " triangles." << endl;
     cout << " there are " << icosahedron->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfPoints() << " points " << endl;

     vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataAlgorithm> subdivisionFilter;
     subdivisionFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLinearSubdivisionFilter>::New();
     dynamic_cast<vtkLinearSubdivisionFilter *> (subdivisionFilter.GetPointer())->SetNumberOfSubdivisions(2);
     subdivisionFilter->SetInput(icosahedron->GetOutput());
     subdivisionFilter->Update();

     cout << " After " << endl;
     std::cout << "    There are " << subdivisionFilter->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfPoints() << " points." << std::endl;
     std::cout << "    There are " << subdivisionFilter->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfPolys() << " triangles." << std::endl;


     vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
     mapper->SetInputConnection(subdivisionFilter->GetOutputPort());

     vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
     actor->SetMapper(mapper);

     vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
     vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();

     renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

     vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
     renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

     //Add the actors to the scene
     renderer->AddActor(actor);
     renderer->SetBackground(.1, .2, .3);

     //Render and interact
     renderWindow->Render();
     renderWindowInteractor->Start();
```

The console output is:

```
 Centre is 0, 0, 0
    There are 20 triangles.
 there are 12 points 
 After 
    There are 162 points.
    There are 320 triangles.
```

Confirming that it has indeed been subdivided.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, the question is how to display it? As stated above, it displays the original un-subdivided icosahedron not the subdivided one despite passing the `subdivisionFilter->GetOutputPort()` to the mapper.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the divisions after turning on wireframe mode:

```
#include <vtkProperty.h>
....
actor->GetProperty()->SetRepresentationToWireframe();
```

What you are seeing is that the algorithm is adding the new points in the same plane as the existing triangle, so when you render the result as a surface it does not look any different.